# How to secure "Azure Storage Queues" for each tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm building a queue messaging system in Azure and what I'm trying to do is an outbound message queue container in Azure Storage Queue that allows my desktop Windows Services to get the latest messages from that queue. The problem I'm facing is that I want to have multiple queues per tenant (each Windows service serves one client) in one storage account. As far as I see, there is no way to restrict the connection string access to each queue. On the other hand, it is not practical for me to create one storage account per tenant. What is the best way to restrict client access to one specific queue with the current security methods available in Azure? I was thinking about using Service Bus Queues, but even that doesn't solve the connection string issue I have in the client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think service bus queues *is* your answer; they allow a multi-subscriber model with "subjects" and various filters etc.

Storage queues are very simplistic and are not the right answer for this particular scenario.

Sorry, on my mobile so haven't got all the relevant docs to hand.

Comment: Aren't *topics* the ones with subjects and filters, and not queues?

Comment: @juunas Yes, technically true, though part of the same tech. But for what the OP is talking about it, it sounds like the right answer.

Comment: The difference is that I can create queue specific keys without creating user accounts. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: The "Shared Access Policy" on each queue will generate a queue specific key with permission level.

Comment: Just be careful with the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) - it's really easy to hit these in a multi-tenant system. I really wish the limitations weren't so... limiting!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use AAD identities and Storage's AAD authentication support (which is currently in public preview).

You would need a Service Principal in Azure AD for each tenant for this,
and add the principal to the *Storage Queue Data Reader* or *Storage Queue Data Contributor* role on their respective queue.

You can then use the principal's credentials to get an access token that is tenant-specific.

Documentation:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/

https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-with-azure-storage-and-managed-service-identity

Comment: Thanks. I looked into this and it seems to be working but it would work if I create one AAD principle per client. My goal is to use a dedicated key without making a user account per tenant. Is it possible to achieve this without creating a user account?

Comment: Well, it is not a user account. It is a service principal. You create an Application + Service Principal via the Graph API per client and get individual keys per tenant. If you want to isolate access then you need separate keys per client right?